# Excel date formula to find if date in a cell is of current, next or previous month

Tags: excel-formula

Can anyone advise how can I find if the given date in a cell belongs to the current month or previous month or next month of the year.

For Example

```
 A               B (result I want to achieve...)       
 05/12/2014      Last month     
 06/12/2014      Current month    
 07/17/2014      Next month
 06/14/2012      Past date
```

I am sorry if you find this question is a duplicate. I'll appreciate if you could guide me to the post where this question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirstOfThisMonth:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), 1)
```

FirstOfNextMonth:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()) + 1, 1)
```

FirstOfLastMonth:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()) - 1, 1)
```

FirstOfMonthAfterNext:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()) + 2, 1)
```

Therefore:

```
=IF(A2 < FirstOfLastMonth,
    "Past Date",
    IF(A2 >= FirstOfMonthAfterNext,
        "Future Date",
        If(A2 >= FirstOfNextMonth,
            "Next Month",
            "Current Month"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Many Thanks gvee, it works fine for me. The formula is recognizing all dates (Past, present future). Thanks again, Cheers..!

Answer (score 0):

You can say something like:

=(YEAR(A1) = YEAR(B1))    AND    (MONTH(A1)=MONTH(B1) )

This will give you a boolean value which you can use in other cells.

Comment: What about different years?

Comment: so that checks if A1 and B1 are in the same year and month.. what about previous/next month? I think you should re-read the full question `:-)`